# Soft delete with foreign key checking in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6

Is there a way to enforce foreign key integrity on a soft delete (as opposed to actually deleting the record)? It seems to me that there should be a way to check this without actually attempting to delete the record in question. Alternatively, is there an easy way to check if that delete would fail without actually attempting the delete (checking to see if that column is actively and currently used as a foreign key in another table).

Perhaps it's possible to utilize the transaction feature in EF6 to rollback a successful delete? (I know that's not quite how it works or what it's intended for)

Not that it's ultimately important, but the target language is Vb.Net

Comment: Have foreign keys at the database level?

Comment: I do not know of any "can delete" functionality in MS SQL or other databases. So EF will have a hard time to find out.

Comment: Yes, they are defined and set to be enforced.

Comment: @HolgerThiemann: this kind of scares me because we have a massive table with about 10 foreign keys. I don't want to have to do manual checks on the referenced tables.

Comment: If you try to delete something EF that has this kind of constraint it will not allow it and will throw an exception.

Comment: Right but we're doing soft deletes which means a record modification, not an actual delete.

Comment: One (dirty) solution would be to start a transaction(scope), delete the record and check if succeeded. Then roll back the transaction in either case (deleted records are back then) and do your soft delete. But be aware that this test and the soft delete are in different transactions and there could someone intervene. Another (cleaner) solution would be an own approach with reflection.

Comment: Hrm, I have to wonder how the reflection for that would be crafted. It's something I'll think about as the project progresses and we'll revisit that if we get time. For now though, we're just checking all the tables with references and return "I'm sorry, Dave" if that value is used.